# Nagios XI APIs to be changed to Nagios core APIs

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

We are using nagios XI APIs (create and query a host, host group, service etc) in out application. We had used CURL and now converted to REST via request module. We now want to implement the same using nagios core module. Is it possible? Does the API remain same? Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios Core does not contain a rest API like XI, this is additional functionality that Nagios XI provides.

Comment: Hello Scott. Thanks a ton. Any chance of using CURL commands since REST is not available in Nagios core?

Comment: Nagios Core doesn't have an API for creating new objects, but it does for querying data, you can use /nagios/jsonquery.html for that.